# Keycloak giving 401 Unauthorized error on app startup

Tags: jwt, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

I was working on Keycloak for this project and it was working fine till I enabled the client Authentication and Authorization. Before this when ever I started my project it used to redirect me to the Keycloak login page. But after enabling authorization it does not redirect me to the keycloak login page.

[client settings I enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd7K8.png)

here is the authorization code and it is giving me unauthorized error.

```
 const keyCloakOptions = {
    url: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_URL,
    realm: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    KeycloakResponseType: 'code',
  };

  const keycloak = new Keycloak(keyCloakOptions);
  const initOptions = { pkceMethod: 'S256' };

const loadingComponent = (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      flexDirection="column"
    >
      <CircularProgress />
      <Typography>Initializing...</Typography>
    </Box>
  );

<ReactKeycloakProvider
      authClient={keycloak}
      initOptions={initOptions}
      LoadingComponent={loadingComponent}
      onEvent={(event, error) => handleOnEvent(event, error)}
    >...</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

here is the payload and call header

[api call header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKqkc.png)

[payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZjX8.png)

Strange thing is, I have created an instance of `KcAdminClient` for the same client after enabling the authorization, and it returns `200 Ok` message. Here is the instance, header and payload.

```
import KcAdminClient from '@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client';

const kcAdminClient = new KcAdminClient();

kcAdminClient.setConfig({
  realmName: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_URL,
});

kcAdminClient
  .auth({
    username: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD,
    grantType: 'password',
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: 'L3AdFRCf9NgveC2HJayrxLizyDEgxGzH',
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully authenticated!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Authentication failed!', err);
  });

export default kcAdminClient;
```

[api header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJifJ.png)
[payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zypmv.png)

Both are making same calls, one is returning `401 unauthorized` message and other is returning `200 OK` message. And it does not redirect app to keycloak login page on start up.

I tried to disable Client Authentication and Authorization and then run it again and it worked fine. It redirected me to Keycloak login page.